# Angular Module fails to load with firebase

Tags: angularjs, firebase

I am new to angular and I have been trying to instantiate an angular module with firebase but it keeps giving me:

Failed to instantiate module myApp due to:

```
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'myApp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

Here is my app.js:

```
var app =  angular.module('myApp',[]);

app.controller('myController', function($scope){

        $scope.names = "Coder01";


});
```

Html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html ng-app='myApp'>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0-beta.2/angular.js"></script> 
        <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/live/3.0/firebase.js"></script>


        <script>

          var config = {
            apiKey: "AIzaSyBTY8XluWdgHFadZLwhlCiD5aupBBTkezU",
            authDomain: "chatroom-60d2f.firebaseapp.com",
            databaseURL: "https://chatroom-60d2f.firebaseio.com",
            storageBucket: "chatroom-60d2f.appspot.com",
          };
          firebase.initializeApp(config);
        </script>
        <script src="js/app.js"></script> 

        <title>Welcome to ChatRoom</title>

      </head>
      <body ng-controller="myController">

        <p>Input something in the input box:</p>
        <p>Name : <input type="text" ng-model="names" placeholder="Enter name here"></p>
        <h1>Hello {{names}}</h1>

        </body>
    </html>
```

Here are all my errors:

```
VM3476:5 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'removeAttribute' of null(anonymous function) @ VM3310:5(anonymous function) @ VM3310:20

app.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

angular.js:68 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] 

Failed to instantiate module myApp due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'myApp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.


VM3400:5 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'removeAttribute' of null
```

Comment: Not entirely sure, what the error might be that you are initializing `firebase` before `js/app.js`. Try putting the `firebase` script block after you include js/app.js. Better yet, you could try putting that code in the controller itself

Answer (score 1):

Error: Failed to instantiate module myApp...... Means your angular module(myApp) is not found/loaded.

Fix the path for app.js file

```
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
```

I ran your code is plunker and it is perfectly fine.

https://plnkr.co/edit/dYDOi667aPb5LBpIncJ0